# ¿Como crear una ventana modal con tan solo HTML y CSS?

Tags: html, html5, css, css3

[image: Ventana Modal]

Hola amigos, podrian explicarme por favor de forma detallada como crear una ventana modal con tan solo HTML y CSS. Lo que planeo es que cuando llene un formulario y haga click en el boton se abra una ventana modal diciendo que la informacion se ha enviado correctamente. Espero puedan ayudarme y muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado mi estimado?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Este ejemplo puedes adaptarlo a tu página, el link `<a href="#openModal">Lanzar el modal</a>` es el que abre el modal cuando le haces click, ya que tiene como referencia la id del div que contiene al modal.

```css
.modalDialog {
 position: fixed;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 z-index: 99999;
 opacity:0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
 opacity:1;
 pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
 width: 400px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 10% auto;
 padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: #fff;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
}
.close {
 background: #606061;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 line-height: 25px;
 position: absolute;
 right: -12px;
 text-align: center;
 top: -10px;
 width: 24px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
 -moz-border-radius: 12px;
 border-radius: 12px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
```

```html
<a href="#openModal">Lanzar el modal</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
 <div>
  <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
  <h2>Mi modal</h2>
  <p>Este es un ejemplo de modal, creado gracias al poder de CSS3.</p>
  <p>Puedes hacer un montón de cosas aquí, como alertas o incluso crear un formulario de registro aquí mismo.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Si te cuesta adaptarlo a tu página, podrías poner algo de código de tu form para orientarte.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Y en donde lo puede agregar, es que al hacerlo mi pagina se descuadra un poco

Comment: Es decir el codigo HTMl en que parte del documento se coloca

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon algo de código para poder darte esa respuesta. Necesito ver el formulario y el botón que dices que quieres dar click para que se muestre el modal.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya pude solucionar el problema.

Comment: Perdon amigos me surgio otro problema, me preguntaba como puedo abrir una ventana modal desde el boton de un formulario, ya que cuando hago esto realiza el action de la pagina o la vuelve a cargar.

Comment: El código html que te di, es un modal, lo único que tienes que hacer es poner en el botón de tu formulario, el siguiente atributo: href="#openmodal", lo que hará que cuando apretes ese botón, se active la div de id="openModal" que también está en el trozo de html que te di. Por supuesto también debes incluir ese css dentro de tu archivo o linkearlo desde un archivo .css aparte. Por eso te repito "EDITA TU PREGUNTA Y MUESTRA ALGO DEL CÓDIGO QUE YA TIENES HECHO, PARA AYUDARTE A ACOMODAR EL MODAL AL BOTÓN DE TU FORMULARIO". Disculpa las mayúsculas, es que no sé como resaltar con negrita.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda amigo

Comment: De nada, que te vaya bien.

Comment: Funciona excelente, solo tuve que reajustar el padding por defecto

Comment: Excelente Aporte, práctico y facil de usar y mejorar