# ¿Cómo abrir ventana modal con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html5, modal

En [otra publicación en el sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/72918/como-crear-una-ventana-modal-con-tan-solo-html-y-css/157877#157877) encontré la solución para hacer una ventana modal. La duda que tengo es si puedo abrir ese modal con JavaScript sin la necesidad de pinchar el enlace.

El código de lo que estoy hablando:

```css
.modalDialog {
 position: fixed;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 z-index: 99999;
 opacity:0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
 opacity:1;
 pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
 width: 400px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 10% auto;
 padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: #fff;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
}
.close {
 background: #606061;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 line-height: 25px;
 position: absolute;
 right: -12px;
 text-align: center;
 top: -10px;
 width: 24px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
 -moz-border-radius: 12px;
 border-radius: 12px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
```

```html
<a href="#openModal">Lanzar el modal</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
 <div>
  <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
  <h2>Mi modal</h2>
  <p>Este es un ejemplo de modal, creado gracias al poder de CSS3.</p>
  <p>Puedes hacer un montón de cosas aquí, como alertas o incluso crear un formulario de registro aquí mismo.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Si no pones el codigo de lo que has intentado no podemos ayudarte.

Comment: Amigo @Manuel Jesús Carrasco Carvajal, creo que la pregunta esta mal redactada, sin embargo entiendo un poco la pregunta. 
Creo lo mas conveniente es que utilices Bootstrap y con ellos puedes personalizar tus funciones con JavaScript para abrir el modal a tu propia necesidad.

Comment: Yo creo que lo importante aquí es ... en qué evento quieres abrir el modal con JS si no es con el click en el enlace?
Cuándo ha de abrirse? en un mouseover? A los 10 segundos de cargarse el DOM? En caso de que el usuario quiera cerrar la ventana?

Aparte, el código que nos has puesto es CSS... y entiendo que lo que necesitas es un código JS que, en caso de tener algo ya, podrías poner para que viéramos por dónde vas

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar [eventos](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp) de javascript según desde donde quieras abrir el modal. Si por ejemplo quisieras mostrar la ventana cuando se carga la página, podrías usar el evento onLoad.

En el ejemplo elimino las propiedades css ***opacity*** que mostraba u ocultaba la ventana y añado a ***.modalDialog*** la propiedad ***display:none*** para ocultar la capa.

Luego creo dos funciones javascript, ***showModal()*** y ***CloseModal()*** que, valga la redundancia, abren o cierran la ventana modal jugando con la propiedad ***display*** que he mencionado antes.

Por último, asigno al evento onload del body la función ***showModal()*** para que lo abra nada más cargar la página. Aquí es donde puedes jugar asignando la función ***showModal()*** a un evento u otro dependiendo de lo que quieras. A demás, también creo otro evento al hacer click en el botón cerrar para ocultar la ventana modal.

```js
function showModal() {
  document.getElementById('openModal').style.display = 'block';
}

function CloseModal() {
  document.getElementById('openModal').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.modalDialog {
 position: fixed;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 z-index: 99999;
 display:none;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
 width: 400px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 10% auto;
 padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: #fff;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
}
.close {
 background: #606061;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 line-height: 25px;
 position: absolute;
 right: -12px;
 text-align: center;
 top: -10px;
 width: 24px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
 -moz-border-radius: 12px;
 border-radius: 12px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
```

```html
<html>
  <body onload="javascript:showModal();">
    <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
      <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close" onclick="javascript:CloseModal();">X</a>
        <h2>Mi modal</h2>
        <p>Este es un ejemplo de modal, creado gracias al poder de CSS3.</p>
        <p>Puedes hacer un montón de cosas aquí, como alertas o incluso crear un formulario de registro aquí mismo.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```