# ¿Como abrir un Formulario modal dentro de la plataforma de google apps script?

Tags: jquery, html5, google-apps-script

Buen dia,

Me gustaría saber como puedo mostrar el dato seleccionado de una tabla en un formulario modal dentro de la plataforma de google app script, intente realizarlo con el código que se había dado en una respuesta anterior ([pregunta][1]), pero no me fue posible, al parecer no se ejecuta de la misma forma dentro de esta plataforma. A continuación publico el código que tengo y con el cual puedo filtrar una tabla y obtener la fila en la que hago click y la primera celda de esta fila.

Muchas gracias.

```css
.topnav {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav-centered a {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.topnav-right {
  float: right;
}


/* Responsive navigation menu (for mobile devices) */

@media screen and (max-width: 200px) {
  .topnav a,
  .topnav-right {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  .topnav-centered a {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: none;
  }
}

TABLE {
  margin-left: 179px;
  margin-right: auto
}

input {
  <!-- dar formato al cudro de texto -->width: 250px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.redondeadonorelieve {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #39c;
}

.boton {
  <!-- dar formato a los botones -->border: 1px solid #39c;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(56, 47, 45, 1);
  color: white;
}

.boton:hover {
  border: solid;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(136, 139, 141, 1);
  color: white;
}

.boton1 {
  border: 1px solid #39c;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(118, 35, 47, 1);
  color: white;
}

.boton1:hover {
  border: solid;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(213, 0, 50, 1);
  color: black;
}

.select {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #39c color: black;
  background-color: white
}

table#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

table#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff;
}

table#t01 th {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('');
  /* Add a search icon to input */
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  /* Position the search icon */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* Do not repeat the icon image */
  width: 25%;
  /* Full-width */
  font-size: 16px;
  /* Increase font-size */
  /*  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px; /* Add some padding */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* Add a grey border */
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  /* Add some space below the input */
}

select#buscar {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #39c color: black;
  background-color: white font-size: 16px;
  /* Increase font-size */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <base target="_top">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    .titulo_boton {
      float: left;
      padding: 5px;
      background-color: #e6e6e6;
      width: 400px;
      font-family: helvetica;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .boton_mostrar {
      float: right;
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 20px;
      color: #DE7217;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="topnav">
    <!--Barra superior-->
    <a href="<?!= rutaWeb ?>">Registrar</a>
    <a href="<?!= rutaWeb + '?p=Buscar' ?>">Buscar</a>
  </div>

  <h1 id="main-heading">Filtrar en tabla</h1>


  <form id="myForm" onKeypress="if(event.keyCode == 13) event.returnValue = false;">
    <select title="Se debe seleccionar una opcion" name="buscar" id="buscar" required>
      <option value="COL 1"> COL 1 </option>
      <option value="COL 2"> COL 2 </option>
      <option value="COL 3"> COL 3 </option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Busqueda por ...">
    <br>


    <table id='t01' class="egt">
      <tr>
        <td>COL 1</td>
        <td>COL 2</td>
        <td>COL 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Celda 1</td>
        <td>Celda 2</td>
        <td>Celda 3</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Celda 4</td>
        <td>Celda 5</td>
        <td>Celda 6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Celda 7</td>
        <td>Celda 8</td>
        <td>Celda 9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Celda 10</td>
        <td>Celda 11</td>
        <td>Celda 12</td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </form>

</body>

</html>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    // Declare variables 
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue, col;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    col = document.getElementById("buscar").selectedIndex
    table = document.getElementById("t01");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[col];
      if (td) {
        txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  }

  $('#t01').find('tr').click(function() {
    alert('You clicked row ' + ($(this).index() + 1));
  });

  $('#t01').find('tr').click(function() {
    var row = $(this).find('td:first').text();
    alert('You clicked ' + row);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Bienvenido. No se incluyó el enlace a la pregunta que haces referencia, por otro lado, falta que incluyas el código del lado del servidor así como los mensajes de error.

Comment: Hola, el enlace que quería mostrar era el siguiente [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/157884/c%C3%B3mo-abrir-ventana-modal-con-javascript), por otro lado, no tengo mensajes de error ya que al momento de intentar ubicar el código de ese enlace en la plataforma de Google simplemente no pasa nada y el resto de códigos se ejecuta con normalidad. En cuanto al código del lado del servidor solo tengo la función doGet.

Comment: Por favor has clic en [edit] para agregar el enlace y el código de la función doGet a la pregunta. Por cierto, cuando estés en eso elimina el "Buen día" y "Muchas Gracias" pues según la guía de comportamiento de este sitio no se den incluir (y si puedes el Stack Snippet, pues este es sólo para HTML/CSS/JavaScript "puro", tu código es una plantilla y no se puede ejecutar aquí)