# Modal no automatico al cargar página

Tags: html, css, html5, modal

Ocupo el siguiente código para mostrar/ocultar un modal con HTML+CSS y solo quiero que abra el modal cuando yo doy el click, pero éste se abre automáticamente cuando carga la página. Sí sirve bien cuando le doy click al link pero igual cuando le doy F5 y automáticamente me abre.

Estoy utilizando el [código que se comparte en esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/72918/como-crear-una-ventana-modal-con-tan-solo-html-y-css):

```css
.modalDialog {
 position: fixed;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 z-index: 99999;
 opacity:0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
 opacity:1;
 pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
 width: 400px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 10% auto;
 padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: #fff;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
}
.close {
 background: #606061;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 line-height: 25px;
 position: absolute;
 right: -12px;
 text-align: center;
 top: -10px;
 width: 24px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
 -moz-border-radius: 12px;
 border-radius: 12px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
```

```html
<a href="#openModal">Lanzar el modal</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
 <div>
  <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
  <h2>Mi modal</h2>
  <p>Este es un ejemplo de modal, creado gracias al poder de CSS3.</p>
  <p>Puedes hacer un montón de cosas aquí, como alertas o incluso crear un formulario de registro aquí mismo.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias probar poniendo por defecto en el css `display: none` y cuando le des click cambia a `display: block` pero ocuparias javascript para hacer eso

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con este estilo y otra cosa cuando declares un id="myModal" crea un button o un href mandalo `<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>` sin que sea una clase #

```
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

Referencia:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233550/launch-bootstrap-modal-on-page-load